# (JAVA) How to create basic text entry and output for Football League Standings?

Tags: java, netbeans

i have an assignment (Java using Netbeans to input Club Name, Input Score, and then Print the table-like league standings. 
Each line displays the outcome of our input, and show the standings like it should (CLUB Name with biggest point is on top of the table:
Here's what i mean: (user input in **BOLD**)

Input No. of Clubs : **4**
Input club 1 : **ManUtd**
Input club 2 : **Liverpool**
Input club 3 : **Chelsea**
Input club 4 : **Arsenal**

Input Score:
ManUtd x Liverpool : **1 1**
ManUtd x Chelsea : **1 0**
ManUtd x Arsenal: **1 0**
Liverpool x Chelsea : **1 1**
Liverpool x Arsenal : **1 0**
Chelsea x Arsenal : **1 1**

and displays the output of team records like this :

Team   Played   Win    Draw    Lose   Pts
Manutd 3 2 1 0 7
Liverpool 3 1 2 0 5
Chelsea 3 0 2 1 2
Arsenal 3 0 1 2 1

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I have tried to connect the whole knowledge that I have ever read from the textbook but it's not working good. But don't know how to use the array, looping function, integer/data from that input .I cannot really realise the hint that can guide me to the solution. Anyone can help me please? I have just learned java by myself and COVID-19 makes studies difficult to meet up to my lecturer.

For anyone who reply this, thanks for the help :)

my basic code stuck in here:

```
package standings;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class LeagueStandings {

public static void main(String[] args) {
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));
int data = 0;
String[] nama    = new String[30];


System.out.println("CLUB NAME");

System.out.println("+===============INPUTAN============================+");
try{
    System.out.println("How Many Clubs ? = ");
    data = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
    for (int a=1;a<=data;a++){
     System.out.println("------Club No."+ a +"------");
     System.out.println("Enter club name        = ");
        nama[a] = input.readLine();

     }
} catch (IOException e ){
  System.out.println("Error");
}

}
```

The result expected like this (result expected from the lecturer)

[image: expected result]

Comment: Have you tried writing any code? What did you write?

Comment: Hello, i already post my basic input code, i don't know how to process that code using array and function to make output like the assignment asks, and i already upload an image, which is the expected result from the task. thank you

Comment: Hi, have you got your solution or still need some help?

Comment: hello, i still need help solving this, can anyone help to solve the case ? thank you...

Comment: Sure. I will post the answer by evening.

Comment: will be waiting up for that, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem. I tried to write as naive solution as possible as you are a beginner.

```
package com.standings;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class LeagueStandings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int data = 0;
            System.out.print("Input number of clubs:\t");
            data = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
            String[] teamList = new String[data];
            for (int i = 0; i < data; i++) {
                System.out.print("Enter club " + (i + 1) + " :\t");
                teamList[i] = input.readLine();
            }

            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");

            // representing 2D array of team score board where each scoreBoard is of type
            //     0      1      2      3       4
            // [played] [win] [draw] [loose] [points]
            int[][] scoreBoard = new int[data][5];
            for (int i = 0; i < data - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < data; j++) {
                    System.out.print(teamList[i] + " X " + teamList[j] + " : ");
                    String score = input.readLine();
                    List<String> scoreList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(score.split(" ")));
                    scoreList.removeIf(s -> s.equals(""));
                    int teamAScore = Integer.parseInt(scoreList.get(0));
                    int teamBScore = Integer.parseInt(scoreList.get(1));
                    scoreBoard[i][0]++;
                    scoreBoard[j][0]++;
                    if (teamAScore > teamBScore) {
                        scoreBoard[i][1]++;
                        scoreBoard[j][3]++;
                        scoreBoard[i][4] += 3;
                    } else if (teamAScore == teamBScore) {
                        scoreBoard[i][2]++;
                        scoreBoard[j][2]++;
                        scoreBoard[i][4]++;
                        scoreBoard[j][4]++;
                    } else {
                        scoreBoard[i][3]++;
                        scoreBoard[j][1]++;
                        scoreBoard[j][4] += 3;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.format("%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s\n", "TEAMS", "PLAYED", "WIN", "DRAW", "LOOSE", "POINTS");
            for (int i = 0; i < data; i++) {
                System.out.format("%15s", teamList[i]);
                System.out.format("%15d%15d%15d%15d%15d\n", scoreBoard[i][0], scoreBoard[i][1], scoreBoard[i][2], scoreBoard[i][3], scoreBoard[i][4]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, really appreciate your help.

Comment: will do! but i have to make my rep to 15 first before i can upvoting ans n quest hehehe, btw thank you so much for you help!